# How to stop the user moving the console window in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, console-application

I'm currently taking computer science A-Level so it should be obvious how to do this as I have been using VB.Net for a year already. However, I have developed a console application which uses the threading.thread.sleep() function to keep track of timings. This is so far the best way I have found to do so but after some destructive testing I have found when the user drags the console around quickly this slows the program down and causes the timings to be wrong. So, is there any way to stop the user from moving a console window, essentially keeping the location of the console fixed, in vb.Net? I'm currently using Visual Studio 2015.

Many Thanks,
Dan

Comment: It is likely that a Timer would work better. There are a few to select from: [Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](https://web.archive.org/web/20150329101415/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) - choose wisely.

Answer (score 1):

Although it may be possible to stop the window being dragged, it is the wrong approach. Sleeping a thread is not an accurate way of maintaining timing data.

Moving the window is not the only action on a windows system that will slow the application down and you're beginning to interfere with the standard windows experience.

I assume you have code that increments the amount of delay after each sleep.

Instead: To maintain accuracy you should store the value of DateTime.Now when the application starts timing.

```
dim mStartTime = DateTime.Now
```

And then get the time differences relative to this.

```
dim elapsedMilliseconds = (DateTime.Now - mStartTime).TotalMilliseconds
```

All timers / sleep rountines are subject to timing error due to system priority / loads. This approach will prevent those errors accumulating.

---

Modifying the console is not easy from .net (you need to use the windows api), however it's pretty simple to prevent the user from doing this if you're using winforms. Maybe you could change your application type.

Comment: `DateTime.UtcNow` would prevent strange errors if the program is running when the computer changes between daylight and standard time. However, the system clock could be changed for other reasons at any time, e.g. to correct it. A [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) would be safer.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - agreed, a StopWatch would be safer. Interestingly enough though the daylight savings change won't affect the code in it's current state as all timezone information is cached (i'm assuming for this very reason).